# How do I decide what CPU cooler to buy?

Tags: cooling, cpu-cooler

I'm building an HTPC and I already have a motherboard with an Intel socket 1150 so I have a half idea what CPU to get. Now I also need a cooler, and that choice is just as overwhelming; there are so many different types.

Can you point me to some factors I can consider, to narrow down my list of options?

- I know it should be air cooled, not water.
- I know there's limited space in the case, so I need to check the physical dimensions of the coolers I'm looking at.
- I want it to be *silent* or at least as silent as possible. I have good experiences with Scythe fans and 'm not afraid to swap the fan of a unit if that's what it takes.
- What else should I think about before I buy?

Comment: @LPChip OP's asking about figuring out which CPU _COOLER_ to buy. :)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I must've clicked the same post twice, because it seemed to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

> "What else should I think about before I buy?"

Nothing, you've covered it.

Basically it should be compatible with the socket, fit in the case and move air. If you're worried about noise levels you'll have to test a few with your ears to choose a quiet one.

Start with the one that comes with the CPU and work from there if it doesn't suffice.

Comment: Thanks. From experience I know that Intels boxed coolers are horrible, but easy to replace.

Comment: You must have considerably different experience than I to say they're "horrible".  Since about the Core 2 Duo days the Intel coolers included in the boxes have been very quiet, and they've _always_ been very good at lasting a long time.  But hey, after more than a decade building Intel PCs daily, I haven't built a PC in a couple years now, so maybe things changed since then (but I doubt it). ;)

Comment: my experience is older, so I might simply try one out and see how it performs. Thanks!